# Bugs with IE-specific gradient filters + rounded corners. Consider removing from UX.SE stylesheet

Tags: bug, status-completed

The UX.SE CSS for tags (`.post-tag`) and buttons(`input[type="submit"], input[type="button"]`)  breaks in IE9+ and WP7+ browsers.  The background gradient overflows the rounded corners.  Like this (enlarging for clarity):

[image]

This is a known problem with the combiation of `border-radius` and the IE-proprietary gradient `filter`. See https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/2046 for more info about the problem.

There are workarounds (e.g. wrapping the <a> in another tag with `overflow:none`, using a background image, etc.). But it's also probably OK to simply remove the `filter:` gradient from any element that also has a `border-radius`.  This means IE users won't see gradients on tags or buttons, but at least the site won't look buggy.

Given the infrequent usage of IE among UX.SE regulars I don't think fixing this is a high priority, but there are IE users coming in from Google to read our posts and it may hurt the site's credibility to look bad on a popular modern browser.

Answer (score 2):

For now, we have removed gradient for the tags, for IE only. The fix will be in the next prod build.